# Simultaneous dasboards running on Rpi (Dashing.io)?

Tags: dashing

I have Dashing.io running on my Rpi and would like to know if it's possible to run simultaneous dashboards at same time and switch between?

Can't found any information about...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have all the dashboards in one place, but cycle through them.

https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6670630